# Error: No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angularjs, angular, hybrid, ng-upgrade

I'm attempting to share a custom angularjs service with an angular component using UpgradeModule and am following the pattern in the Angular documentation. I am including the path to my "working" plunker code. I have commneted out the code that breaks the application in app.ts file so that we can see the hybrid app working until the point that I attempt to share the service with angular. I think it's complaining about my attempt to inject the service using the component facory method.

```
 export function sayHelloServiceFactory(i: string) {
  return i.get('sayHelloService');
}

export const sayHelloServiceProvider = {
  provide: SayHelloService,
  useFactory: sayHelloServiceFactory,
  deps: ['$injector']
};
```

[angularJS / angular hybrid plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/4TXoCy36Yke5TbHPJ1Hm)
here is the link to my plunk. please help.

Comment: I am able to downgrade an Angular service to work in an AngularJS component!!! so, must be because, I am bootstrapping the angular app first.